# Acces non-static data from static initialization of static field in Haxe

Tags: haxe, openfl

I'm trying to initialize a static class field in Haxe with a Float value, but the compiler complains about the initializer being invalid.

I don't have a lot of experience using Haxe, so if anyone can help me I would be really grateful.

Here is the code:

[image: Enemy.hx]

And here is the error:

[image: cmd]

Comment: If `Lib.current.stage.stageWidth` was a static field, it would work. To fix it you can also make radius not static, and set the radius in the constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Invalid field access" is basically a null reference error, meaning that `Lib.current.stage` is `null` at the time that static fields are initialized. As a workaround, you could use a property with a getter so that it's accessed later:

```
public static var radius(get, never):Float;

private static function get_radius():Float
{
    return Lib.current.stage.stageWidth / 35;
}
```